# Simulating array_pop for various structures in C

Tags: c

I am new to C but I am currently working on a project which I cannot work out how I can do what is needed.

I have 2 different struct arrays, they are completely differently defined and I am trying to do the same action as PHP's array_pop would do, i.e. remove the last element of the array structure.

I know I could create 2 separate functions, one for each structure type, but obviously is not the best idea, so am wondering whether it is possible that I can pass either structure type to the one function, and possibly a flag, and the flag determine what type of structure it should be cast to.

My structures are defined as follows

```
typedef struct CallLogSearchResultStruct
{
    long date;
    int dRowIndex;
} callLogSearchResultStruct;

typedef struct CallLogSearchDataStruct
{
    char * date;
    char * time;
    char * bParty;
    char * aParty;
    float duration;
    char * cleardownCause;
    struct CallLogSearchOutboundStruct * outboundLegs;
} callLogSearchDataStruct;
```

Below is how the structures are initialised

```
callLogSearchData = calloc(numRows, sizeof(callLogSearchDataStruct));
callLogSearch = calloc(numRows, sizeof(callLogSearchResultStruct));
```

`numRows` being the number of structs to contain within the array.

Below is how I am using the structures

```
callLogSearchData[dataRow].aParty = NULL;
callLogSearchData[dataRow].bParty = NULL;
callLogSearchData[dataRow].cleardownCause = NULL;
callLogSearchData[dataRow].date = NULL;
callLogSearchData[dataRow].time = NULL;
callLogSearchData[dataRow].outboundLegs = NULL;
```

Apologise if this is a simple straight forward answer, I can't find anything on Google, although not entirely sure what this would be called so maybe I'm using the wrong keywords.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I know it is tagged as "c" question, but might be useful to use c++ templates in the case you have access to a c++ compiler. Templates are designed for this kind of issues.

Comment: For C arrays created with `calloc`, `malloc`, etc., you can't really "remove" the last item in the array without allocating a new array and copying everything except the last item, unless by "remove", you simply mean to copy the object out somewhere else and then mark the entry in the array as empty/unused in some way...

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "remove"? How are the arrays allocated?

If you have an array created by a declaration such as:

```
struct foo my_foos[123];
```

there is nothing you can do to change the fact that `my_foos` is 123 elements long. You can of course select to ignore some of them by having a separate `size_t foo_count` variable that you maintain.

Arrays in C are not generally dynamic (unlike lists/arrays in many more high-level languages). You can implement a dynamic array using `malloc()`, which is not too hard but it's unclear if that's what you've done.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have updated my question, sorry, I forgot the way an array can be created is different, I am using calloc

Answer (score 0):

If you're open for using external files, have a look at [**utarray**](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/utarray.html):

It's a collection of macros stored in **one** header that allow what you're searching for. No need to link an additional library, just `#include` the file and you have what you need.

You'd have to implement a custom `UT_icd` providing functions to init, copy and free the elements stored in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately I can't. It needs to all be done using what is included within C, no external libraries

Comment: well. Macros are included in C. Actually, it's no library but simply a header file with some macro definitions in it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is actually a linked list. It is a collection of structures each one pointing to the Nth element and to the next element in the list. That way you can easily remove any element by unlinking it in the chain. You can google for a linked list lib in C or, implement one (it's a good exercise).
Arrays in C are static memory ranges with only enough space for your elements. Nothing more. In general you can not remove one element. You can, however, use realloc function to resize an existing array.
For what you're trying to do I'd go for a linked list.